# Bash and Zsh profile confusion

Tags: zsh, .bash-profile

I'm on a mac and am about to start developing, did a clean install on my mac just but my question is what is the difference between ~/.bash_profile, ~/.zshrc, ~/.profile, and ~/.bashrc and where can I find the best practices involved with using these files? Also which is being used now on macos because zsh is not the default on terminal? Do I still use bash-profile?

Comment: Srat by reading [Bash Startup Files (Bash Reference Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) and [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)